# Firefox in Linux doesn't interpret 12px Arial correctly, but 1em or 0.9 does

Tags: fonts

The problem is only with 12px and smaller. Other sizes seems to be OK.

Why is that?

If I use `height: 12px;` and the font family is `arial`, it is stretched and not the same height as in Windows.

If I use `0.9em` or `1em` it shows OK.

Why is that?

How can I set Ubuntu to show `12px` as `12px`?

I have installed `ms-fonts` including Arial so there is no problem.

I have already set aliasing to RGBS and hinting is set to `slight`.

**EDIT:**

E.g. here:

[image]

Comment: @l0b0 I have added it to my question.

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the baseline spread is the same on both - I would blame this on glyph rendering. The anti-aliasing algorithms are different on Linux and Windows (and both can be tweaked). You might want to try various settings of hinting - the MS fonts are known for relying on this quite a lot.

As a side-note, it should probably read `font-family: sans-serif` instead of `arial` on a well written page.

Comment: Where can I tweak glyph rendering in Ubuntu to get the Windows look in Ubuntu's browsers?

Comment: I tried to turn off hinting to none and aliasing turn off and the fonts in ubunty are now ugly, but deformation in Ubuntu's Firefox and Chrome on websites is still the same :(. How can I fix that?

Comment: Check http://new-balls.blogspot.cz/2012/06/font-rendering-problem-in-firefox-on.html and about:config options mentioned at http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/927199.

Comment: I doesn't help ;(

Comment: Doesn't help as in *"different but not better"* or *"no change whatsoever"*?

Comment: @pererph I don't understand what do you mean? The links you provided doesn't help. It's about aliasing and smoothness of the fonts. That's not my problem. My problem is that no matter how sharp and hinedt the fonts are (I have tried all combinations) the text under the title is still deformed.

Answer (score 1):

Put a .fonts.conf in your home dir containing:

```
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <test name="family" compare="eq"><string>Arial</string></test>
    <test name="pixelsize" compare="eq"><double>12</double></test>
    <edit name="pixelsize" mode="assign"><double>13</double></edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

This will render Arial 12px into Arial 13px

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172477/fonts-too-small-in-chrome-in-12-04)